# How to hide product in stock from my account page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an issue regarding woocommerce account. It showed some problems and did not allow connection until today, when I just recreated some pages. At the moment it is displaying something at the bottom of the account info, though I can not find that text anywhere in back-end. Can someone help ?

[image: This is what is displayed extra]

Comment: What is the URL?

Comment: This is the link, but I believe it requires to be logged in to be displayed https://multimasimex.ro/contul-meu/  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Chrome web inspector, locate the element you wish to hide on the page and find it's class or ID.

Then use some custom CSS to hide the element, for example:

```
.my-custom-class { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help! I used the inspect and realized it was a rich snippet from some SEO plugin setting and now it is solved.